# Architecture of a Java Project

Tags: java, architecture

I have a single log file for 100 users in text format. I want to extract the log for single user and write it in a different text file.

1. The file location and user-identification will be provided in the properties file.
2. Log4j is used for logging the data.
3. A GUI is created for the purpose which is a kind of console view

I want to know, how to organize the project. Should I keep all the codes in a single class file (that will be too bad).

Comment: Have a look at the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @QBrute Thank you. Which means, I need three classes (property file reading, logging, gui). Am I right ?